# Does Brownian Motion go positive with probability one?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be Brownian Motion $T_a$ the time of first passge for point $a$ for $B_t$. From the reflection principle we know that that:

$P(T_a<t)=P(M_t>a)=2P(B_t>a)$

So, from what I can tell, for any $t>0$, $P(T_0 < t) = 2P(B_t>0)=1$ since $B_t$ is distributed $N(0, t)$. Is this right?

The reason I'm asking is that this seems to say that the set of all paths which area always negative has probability zero - which feel intuitively suspect to me.

Comment: As $B_0 = 0$, we have $T_0 = 0$, so of course $P(T_0<t) = 1$.

Comment: @NN2 right, makes sense. I guess I'm still wondering though since it also means that as $a \rightarrow 0$ that $P(M_t < a) \rightarrow 0$ so it still seems like the probability of any path that starts at $0$, goes negative, and stays negative for _any_ period of time is zero. Is that right?

Comment: I haven't gotten your point yet. Why "probability of any path that starts at 0, goes negative, and stays negative for any period of time is zero" is counter intuitive ?